# MongoError: "Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Query root must be specified."

Tags: azure, parse-server, azure-cosmosdb

For several months, I use ParseServer on azure without problems but since a few hours I'm getting this error:

```
> 2017-02-01T09:23:51.925Z - Uncaught internal server error. { [MongoError: Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}
ActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}\r\nActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p',
_t: 'OKMongoResponse',
ok: 0,
code: 2,
errmsg: 'Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}\r\nActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p',
'$err': 'Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}\r\nActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p' } MongoError: Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}
ActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p
at Function.MongoError.create (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\error.js:31:11)
at D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:462:72
at authenticateStragglers (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:410:16)
at null.messageHandler (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\pool.js:444:5)
at TLSSocket. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\node_modules\parse-server\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\lib\connection\connection.js:306:22)
at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:169:7)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:153:18)
at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:111:10)
at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:536:20)
2017-02-01T09:23:51.925Z - Error generating response. { [MongoError: Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}
ActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p]
name: 'MongoError',
message: 'Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}\r\nActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p',
_t: 'OKMongoResponse',
ok: 0,
code: 2,
errmsg: 'Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}\r\nActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p',
'$err': 'Message: {"Errors":["Encountered exception while executing Javascript. Exception = Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\r\nStack trace: Error: Invalid argument. Query root must be specified.\n at commonUpdate (.sys.commonUpdate.js:2288:17)\n at docDbMain (.sys.commonUpdate.js:4:5)\n at Global code (.sys.commonUpdate.js:1:2)"]}\r\nActivityId: 3a721634-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, Request URI: rntbd://10.100.100.77:14000/apps/f8a35ed9-3dea-410f-a89a-28650ff41381/services/ab284460-dfd9-4fc6-8366-48ae5708818e/partitions/a108a897-4a3c-44f0-aa7d-477d08f77d67/replicas/131193282907353114p' }
```

I've deploy parse server and the DB using the tools brought by Microsoft (https://github.com/felixrieseberg/parse-server-azure).

I encountered the problem on parse server version 2.3.1 and 2.3.2. What I do not understand is that the problem has appeared suddenly on a release (2.3.1) that has worked well until now.

Comment: Did you add any new classes (which would have led to a new collection being created)? And if so: Is that new collection a different type than the other collections (e.g. is it a partitioned collection)? Could it be that you've exercised a different path within Parse, where possibly one of the queries inside the Parse server is incorrectly formatted?

Comment: No I've change nothing and other users encountered the same issue https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/3462

Comment: The fact that others are seeing it, in your issue, points to a potential bug somewhere in the Azure-specific parse updates, or something related to DocumentDB itself. Unfortunately out of scope for StackOverflow, since it's library- or service-specific with no programming solution (other than a fix to the libraries / service in question).

Comment: I have the same error here since this morning.  No changes for the last few weeks.

Comment: I'm contacting Azure support now.

Comment: The Azure team is looking into it.

Comment: Azure team has identified the issue and they are currently deploying a fix.   ETA  2-3 hours.

Comment: This question should now be closed/deleted, as it's not a programming issue, and is not repeatable/reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Azure team should have published a fix.  I'm no longer seeing the crashes.